# Problem with alignment of minipage within a poster

Tags: minipage

I am creating a poster with this template:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\columnsep=100pt 
\columnseprule=3pt    
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}    
\usepackage{times} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.75\linewidth}
\veryHuge\textbf{My title}\\
\huge\textbf{Authors}\\
{\large department}\\

\end{minipage}
%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.12\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{ESA.eps}
\vspace{2cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{UNIURB_2015.jpg}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.12\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{INFN.eps}
\vspace{2cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{LISA-PF_2.eps}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

but I want the four logos at the right of the title: how do I do this?

Comment: If you remove the empty lines between the minipages it will already be closer to what you want.

Comment: @marmot Why does it work?

Comment: An empty line starts a new paragraph, i.e. comes with a line break.